# Why I am not able to run a dynamic web project on JBoss AS 5.1 with correct project facet in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, runtime

I am on `Ubuntu 14.04`, using `eclipse Luna 4.04`, `Java 7` and `Jboss 5.1`
When I created jsp file I am getting this error

```
The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path
```

I know the solution of this error that I need to select the target runtime `jboos 5..1`
but when I go to

```
properties->Targeted Runtime
```

[image]
the jboss5.1 is disable.
how do I resolve this

after adding the target runtime not able to run the project

[image]

**Server tab**
[image: Server tab]

**console after starting the server**
[image: console after staring the server]

**Project facts**
[image: Project facts]

Comment: Does your eclipse support J2EE ?

Comment: yes id does support  J2EE see in image

Comment: The comment below suggests _you may need to uninstall some facets_. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **server runtime libraries** on your build path.

1. Right click on the project
2. Click on Build path
3. Go to the Libraries tab
4. Click on "Add Library"
5. Select Server Runtime
6. Select the installed JBoss Server runtime

If proper **runtime** is not enabled, change the **project facet**

1. Right click on project
2. Properties
3. Project Facet
4. Select Dynamic web project or appropriate facet for your project.

Check the java version, java version should support your application server.
Set the java version as 6 for JBOSS AS 5.1, its not supported by Java 7.

Comment: Not able to run ? means ? You are getting an option to run it on a server ?

Comment: yes I am getting the the option to run on server. when go to run on server it ask me for manually define new server, wherein I have already defined a server. though when i select jboss 5.1 the finish button is disabled

Comment: i'll jsut attach a screen sort  in the question

Comment: Show me the screenshot of your server tab in eclipse.

Comment: I have created it bro. can you please let me know the steps. sorry for being dumb

Comment: Window --> show view --> Servers ...attach the screenshot of your server tab.

Comment: Creating a server steps : File --> New --> Server --> Choose the appropriate server type (In your case JBOSS AS 5.1)--> give the path of the location where you have installed your JBOSS AS 5.1

Comment: Once done you will be able to see a Jboss AS 5.1 server instance in your Servers tab in eclipse.

Comment: did you check that? i have done it. but i don’t know why i am facing the problem?

Comment: Show me the project facet :-(

Comment: bro did you check that, any idea?

Comment: @ Amit Bhati  bro its done. as i was using java 7 it does not support  jboss 5.1, When I install java 6. it worked